# Suppose that the $\lim a_{n} = 1$ and $x < y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $\lim a_{n} = 1$ and $x<y$. Is it possible to show using the Algebriac limit theorem that if the $\lim xa_{n} < y$. Then $0<x<y$?
.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Develop your idea and write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim(y-xa_n)=y-x>0$, hence for $\varepsilon=\dfrac{y-x}{2}$, there exists $N$ s.t for all $n\geq N $ ; $-\varepsilon\le (y-xa_n)-(y-x)\le \varepsilon$, hence 
for all $n\ge N $ ; $0<\dfrac{y-x}{2}=-\varepsilon+(y-x)\le (y-xa_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for $x,y>0$.

Set $\varepsilon=\dfrac{y}{x}-1>0$. Then, as $a_n\to 1$, there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that 
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert a_n-1\rvert<\varepsilon,
$$
and hence
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad  a_n<1+\varepsilon=\frac{y}{x},
$$
or
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad  x\,a_n<y.
$$